# adding a gradient sublayer over the root layer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I need to put a gradient color from top to bottom from transparent to black with 30% opacity. I have found out that best way to do it is to use a CAGradientLayer. I want to add that layer just on top of the "root" layer to avoid creating a separate view for this. It makes more sense to me to have multiple layers than multiple UIViews. So far, this is what I have written with no luck.

```
    // view did load
    var gradientLayer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer();
    gradientLayer.frame = coverView.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor()];
    coverView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, above: coverView.layer);
    // also tried below
    // coverView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0);
```

I want this to show gradient colors on top of the image. The code below doesn't show anything at all. What can you recommend me to try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. The problem happened because of the line:

```
gradientLayer.frame = coverView.bounds;
```

The `coverView.bounds` give a completely different output. Using `coverView.layer.frame` did make the layer the size of the parent layer.

Also the CAGradientLayer colors attribute doesn't like `UIColor`; using CGColor solved that issue. And I used the function with the atIndex attribute. Here is the final code:

```
var gradientLayer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer();
gradientLayer.frame = coverView.layer.frame;
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor!, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor!];
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
gradientLayer.opacity = 0.8;
coverView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0);
```

Comment: u might need to set **gradientLayer.frame = coverView.layer.bounds;** to  obtain correct output